# I cant fix Lua value canceling out other value

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

Okay well I have a piece of code which is a weed pot system for garrysmod Darkrp it allows you to create 4 pots and plant seeds with a timer counting down to complete.
However once another pot is on it cancels the others out and im not sure how i can fix this.

cheers dynamics

```
if hitEnt:GetClass() == "seed_weed" then

  if self.Entity:GetNWBool("Plantable") == true then

    self.Entity:SetNWBool("Plantable", false)

    hitEnt:Remove()
  
    self.Entity:SetModel("models/nater/weedplant_pot_planted.mdl")

    timer.Create("Stage2_", GrowTime/7, 1, function()

      self.Entity:SetModel("models/nater/weedplant_pot_growing1.mdl")

    end)

    timer.Create("Stage3_", GrowTime/6, 1, function()

      self.Entity:SetModel("models/nater/weedplant_pot_growing2.mdl")

    end)

    timer.Create("Stage4_", GrowTime/5, 1, function()

      self.Entity:SetModel("models/nater/weedplant_pot_growing3.mdl")

    end)

    timer.Create("Stage5_", GrowTime/4, 1, function()

      self.Entity:SetModel("models/nater/weedplant_pot_growing4.mdl")
 
    end)

    timer.Create("Stage6_", GrowTime/3, 1, function()

      self.Entity:SetModel("models/nater/weedplant_pot_growing5.mdl")

    end)

    timer.Create("Stage7_", GrowTime/2, 1, function()
 
      self.Entity:SetModel("models/nater/weedplant_pot_growing6.mdl")

    end)
 
    timer.Create("Stage8_", GrowTime/1, 1, function()

      self.Entity:SetModel("models/nater/weedplant_pot_growing7.mdl")

      self.Entity:SetNWBool("Usable", true)

    end)

  end

end

end

function ENT:OnRemove()

  timer.Destroy("Stage2_")

  timer.Destroy("Stage3_")

  timer.Destroy("Stage4_")

  timer.Destroy("Stage5_")
 
  timer.Destroy("Stage6_")

  timer.Destroy("Stage7_")

  timer.Destroy("Stage8_")

end
```

Comment: reduce your code to a [mcve] ! please read [ask] and present your debugging attempts

Comment: please note that we don't even know what self is

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is happening because the timers created are not unique. I.e. you spawn in one pot, which creates a timer called "Stage2_". You then create another pot, which creates another time with the same name "Stage2_", overriding the old one.

Consider adding some sort of unique identifier in the name for each pot that is spawned.

As an example, you could do this by adding a variable that increases by one each time a pot is spawned, then set the name of the timer to `"Stage2_" + variable`.

Make sure the variable is defined in a scope outside of the entity itself, or you will just end up re-declaring the variable each time an instance of the entity is spawned.